# PowerShell - Form button click unsets variable outside the closing brackets

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make a BlackJack game in PowerShell with as sole purpose to learn the language.

Not I've started testing with forms (to select hit/stand) and found the following issue in a form test file:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null

$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "Debug."
$Form.AutoScroll = $True
$Form.AutoSize = $True
$Form.AutoSizeMode = "GrowAndShrink"
$Form.BackColor = "Red"
# $Form.Icon = [system.drawing.icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon("C:\Scripts\Private\SVTserv.ico") ### Commented out because other people don't have this file.
$Form.MinimizeBox = $False
$Form.MaximizeBox = $False
$Form.WindowState = "Normal"
$Form.SizeGripStyle = "Hide"
$Form.ShowInTaskbar = $False
$Form.Opacity = 0.7
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label.Text = "Debug, trigger: @Null."
$Label.AutoSize = $True
$Form.Controls.Add($Label)


$HButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$HButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,120)
$HButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$HButton.Text = "Debug1"
$HButton.Add_Click({
$X = "DATA.DEBUG.1"
Write-Host $X - test1.
$Form.Close()
Write-Host $X - test2.
}
)
Write-Host $X - test3.
$Form.Controls.Add($HButton)

$SButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$SButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,120)
$SButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$SButton.Text = "Debug2"
$SButton.Add_Click({
$X = "DATA.DEBUG.2"
Write-Host $X - test1.
$Form.Close()
Write-Host $X - test2.
}
)
$Form.Controls.Add($SButton)

$Form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
Write-Host $X - test4.
```

Hitting the Debug1 button returns the following output:

```
 - test3.
DATA.DEBUG.1 - test1.
DATA.DEBUG.1 - test2.
 - test4.
```

What I am trying to do here is set variable $X and re-use it later on, I need to use it at the section where it writes the output as test4.

Other usefull information might be my PowerShell version:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> Write-Host $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
4      0      -1     -1
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, can you elaborate? What do you want to happen?

Comment: @Raf Variable $X is not being written where the "Write-Host $X - test4." line is triggered. For Check the output which I have provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `$X` a global variable - replace all instances of `$X` with `$global:X`.

Comment: This worked, thanks. Good to know that powershell uses global variables. Hwoever, will these $Global: variables be stored for use in other seesions as well?

Comment: You can find out more about scopes here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh847849.aspx